# VueJS Array Index returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am creating a poetry app where poetry is fetched using an API call.

I fetch data using `axios` library and do `v-for` to populate data. I use the `index` from `v-for` to populate the image for each poem respectively.

I display 10 results per page using my own custom pagination. Currently, it's only for next button though.

The problem I am facing is when I navigate to Page 2! As I said earlier, that I use `v-for`'s index to display images, it doesn't actually update the index when I move to the next page. As a result, the images are shown same as of page 1.

`Code:`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    proxy: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
    imageIndex: 0,
    pagination: {
      start: 0,
      end: 10,
      resPerPage: 10
    },
    fetchData: [],
    fetchImages: []
  },
  methods: {
    paginate() {
      this.pagination.start = this.pagination.start + this.pagination.resPerPage;
      this.pagination.end = this.pagination.end + this.pagination.resPerPage;
    },
    async fetchDatas() {
      try {
        const res = await axios(`${this.proxy}http://poetrydb.org/author,title/Shakespeare;Sonnet`);
        if (res) {
          this.fetchData = res.data;
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    async fetchImagess() {
      const key = '9520054-7cf775cfe7a0d903224a0f896';
      const perPage = 154;
      const proxy = ''
      const res = await axios(`${this.proxy}https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${key}&per_page=${perPage}`);
      this.fetchImages = res.data.hits;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchDatas();
    this.fetchImagess();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(poetry, index) in fetchData.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end)">
    <div>
      <img :src="fetchImages[index].largeImageURL.toLowerCase()" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;max-height: 320px;">
      <div>
        <h5>{{ poetry.title }}</h5>
        <span v-for="(poetryBody, i) in poetry.lines.slice(0, 5)">
              {{ i === 4 ? poetryBody.split(',').join('') + '...' : poetryBody  }}
            </span>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav style="padding-top: 3em;">
    <button @click="paginate()">Next</button>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sanjaybanjade/vnu654gk/9/

As you can see the images doesn't get updated when I goto Page 2! Please help me fix this!

And please ignore the console errors. I am gonna fix them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix would be to calculate the offset in line 4 to update on pagination:

`<img v-bind:src="fetchImages[index + pagination.start].largeImageURL.toLowerCase()" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;max-height: 320px;">`

Answer (score 0):

wrong at this line `fetchImages[index].largeImageURL.toLowerCase()`.

Since you are iterating a sliced array of fetchData, it's index is related to sliced array, not original array. So, you should apply pagination slice to your fetchImages too.

Comment: Will you please help me with that line? I am still confused about applying the pagination slice to fetchImages.

Comment: I suggest you to use computed properties in this case.@Sanjay
That is, you should just need to update your pagination information whenever user click prev/next button. And computed properties will react to pagination change.
Like this:
`computed: {
  currentImages() {
    return this.fetchImages.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end);
  },
  currentData() {
    return this.fetchData.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end);
  },
}`
use these computed properties in your v-for directives instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you run fetchData.slice(), it returns a new object. So if you slice out 10 new pieces of poetry, their indexes are still going to be 0-9, since the returned object only has that many items each time.

Answer (score 0):

Why it's not working is because you only slice `fetchData` on this line `fetchData.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end)` but you don't slice the `fetchImages` what means `fetchImages` still is the same array it didn't change, meaning that `index 0` is still the same image. Best is if you keep them in sync so I would add a `pageData` and `pageImages` array's and every time you change the paging you update both of them. like in a `updatePageData` method

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      proxy: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
      imageIndex: 0,
      pagination: {
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        resPerPage: 10
      },
      fetchData: [],
      fetchImages: [],
      pageData: [],
      pageImages: []
  },
  methods: {
    paginateNext() {
      this.pagination.start = this.pagination.start + this.pagination.resPerPage;
      this.pagination.end = this.pagination.end + this.pagination.resPerPage;
      this.updatePageData()
    },
    updatePageData () {
     this.pageData = this.fetchData.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end)
      this.pageImages = this.fetchImages.slice(this.pagination.start, this.pagination.end)
    },
    async fetchDatas() {
      try {       
        const res = await axios(`${this.proxy}http://poetrydb.org/author,title/Shakespeare;Sonnet`);
        if(res) {
          this.fetchData = res.data;
        }
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
    async fetchImagess() {
      const key = '9520054-7cf775cfe7a0d903224a0f896';
      const perPage = 154;
      const proxy = ''
      const res = await axios(`${this.proxy}https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${key}&per_page=${perPage}`);
      this.fetchImages = res.data.hits;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
   Promise.all([
     this.fetchDatas(),
      this.fetchImagess()
    ])
    .then(() => this.updatePageData())
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(poetry, index) in pageData">
    <div>
      <img :src="pageImages[index].largeImageURL.toLowerCase()" style="max-width: 100%;height: auto;max-height: 320px;">
      <div>
        <h5>{{ poetry.title }}</h5>
        <span v-for="(poetryBody, i) in poetry.lines.slice(0, 5)">
              {{ i === 4 ? poetryBody.split(',').join('') + '...' : poetryBody  }}
            </span>
        <br>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav style="padding-top: 3em;">
    <button @click="paginateNext()">Next</button>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```